# Hide WSDL in JAX-RPC 1.1 WS

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c, jax-rpc

I have a lot of old web services.
Now the wsdl is public, so i need to hide the wsdl.

My configuration is jax-rpc 1.1 + Weblogic 12.1.3.0.0

I have searched a lot, but none of the solutions found have worked for me:

- I don't have the option in Weblogic to hide the wsdl (in the documentation appears this option but in my weblogic not):
  [image]
- @WSDL(exposed = false) (¿not possible in jax-rpc?)
- Implementing a class with Filter is not working

Does anyone have any idea how to hide the wsdl with this configuration?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved this blocking the GET operations in the webservice (since all SOAP methods use POST )

[image]